# Hi, My selenium script is not working on headless mode but working fine without headless. Error msg (NoSuchElementException)?why?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

My selenium script is not working on headless mode but working fine without headless. Error msg (NoSuchElementException)?why?

Increase time.sleep 2 to 10 but still not working

Comment: Share the code that you use for opening the browser and what is the chrome version you used

Comment: import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.headless = True
ser = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = ser, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

Comment: def test_schema():
 
    driver.get("https://search.google.com/test/rich-results")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[normalize-space()='Sign in']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space()='Next']").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space()='Next']").click()
    time.sleep(5)

Comment: I believe if the script executes fine in Non headless mode then it should definitely execute  fine in headless mode also.  probably there might be some other issue which was foreseen. try running the script multiple times in nonheadless mode you would easily catch the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the applications do not work properly in the headless mode due to the application firewall. In that case, you need to debug what is showing inside headless.

> Take a snapshot using selenium and see what is showing before the element
> not found exception

> If you found your application is blocked to load in headless then follow the steps

To bypass the firewall you can use following argument in your python script. I used it in my java so i mention it in java. You can convert to your desire language

```
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36");
```