# JS is disabled when trying to get page via Selenium "--headless=new"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, twitter, selenium-chromedriver, socks5

The Twitter API is now paid, so now I need to write a parser for the tweet pages. I am using socks5 proxy.

So my first step was to get the tweet page directly through the socks5 proxy. I got a 302 code and an endless redirect.

Then I tried adding cookies and got a "Please enable JS" page.

So now we have decided to use Selenium to get this page. When I try to get the page without `headless=new` there is no problem, but when I try to use that argument, the "please include JS" page reappears.

What I've tried:

- [How to enable JavaScript with headless Chrome in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617101/how-to-enable-javascript-with-headless-chrome-in-selenium/70201673#70201673)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Hi, My selenium script is not working on headless mode but working fine without headless. Error msg (NoSuchElementException)?why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261347/hi-my-selenium-script-is-not-working-on-headless-mode-but-working-fine-without) (Similar to others)

Also I tried to install different user agents, different Selenium libraries, explicitly set the path to the chrome driver (`v114.0.5735.90` driver and google chrome `v114.0.5735.199`) and different browsers (Edge). JS was enabled.

I use the latest library version of the Selenium library, the language is C#

I created a simple console app for easy debugging - the basic code below should work (I believe):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.SocksVersion = 5;
proxy.SocksProxy = "host:port";
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--headless=new");
options.Proxy = proxy;
string pageSource = "";
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://twitter.com/ElonMuskAOC/status/1677171220184469505");
    pageSource = driver.PageSource;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine, JS just needs time to execute). The noscript tag is always on the page and does not require additional time to appear

Comment: The usual way to do this is by using [explicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) for the elements you want to interact with or scrape.